# How do I write an MVC 1 app with MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I went to http://www.asp.net/mvc and the web installer offered me the option to install MVC 2, but not MVC 1.

I thought MVC 2 was still in beta? Either way, I need to write an MVC 1 app. In visual studio, my only choice is either ASP.NET Web Application or ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: MVC 2 is no longer in beta - ASP.NET MVC 2.0 RTM was released on March 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove MVC2 and download and install MVC 1 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't have to remove MVC 2.  You can have v1 and v2 installed side-by-side with no issues.